XGBoost Time Series Diff Feature
Let's suppose I have day 1,2,3,4 and want to predict day 5:
Features = Weekday, Diff
Target = Value
Weekday: 1,2,3,4,5 | Diff: NaN,40,20,20,(?) | Value: 20,60,80,100,(?)
When I train my model using diff() as feature, it really enhances the results. But what is the purpose of using it, if I can't use it to predict future steps?
Is there a way I can use it as my input? Otherwise I don't see the purpose of using diff in my training.
I tried using the diff from last two days as an approximation to fill in day 5, but it really didn't help since my data has a lot of peaks and downs

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

a diff operation will attempt to make the time series stationary (remove the trend): https://xgboosting.com/xgboost-difference-transform-time-series-data/
